# Laptop won't start when Ubuntu SSD is unplugged - move grub

Tags: ubuntu, ssd, grub, ubuntu-20.04

I have a MSI laptop running on Windows 10, for work purposes, I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a SSD which works fine

When I turn on my laptop with the SSD plugged in, a menu appears where I can choose to use:

- Ubuntu
- Ubuntu (recovery mode)
- Windows 10

from then on I can choose the one I want and it works fine

My issue is the following:
When I turn on my laptop with the SSD **NOT** plugged in then no OS starts and I have to use the power button to turn off my laptop

I need to switch every day so I do not want to enter BIOS every time I turn on my laptop

What BIOS config should I use so that:

- When the SSD is not plugged: Windows launches normally
- When the SSD is plugged : Ubuntu launches or I have to choose (either one is fine for me)

Edit: From what I understand, I need to move grub on my windows disk using `grub-install`, however when I look at the disks using `fdisk -l` I get a lot of results. Which disk should I choose and what would be the corresponding command line?

Here is all the results I get:

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 55,52 MiB, 58204160 bytes, 113680 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 4 KiB, 4096 bytes, 8 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 55,45 MiB, 58130432 bytes, 113536 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 248,78 MiB, 260841472 bytes, 509456 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 61,93 MiB, 64917504 bytes, 126792 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 65,1 MiB, 68259840 bytes, 133320 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 61,91 MiB, 64897024 bytes, 126752 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 50,98 MiB, 53432320 bytes, 104360 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 476,96 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk model: KINGSTON OM8PCP3512F-AI1                
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 7FA82927-BACB-47AD-89CA-8A0DC9CABADB

Device             Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048     616447    614400   300M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2    616448     878591    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3    878592  954718207 953839616 454,8G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p4 954718208  956561407   1843200   900M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p5 956561408 1000214527  43653120  20,8G Windows recovery environment


Disk /dev/sda: 465,78 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: Portable SSD T5 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 33553920 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x2728b716

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *     2048 976773167 976771120 465,8G 83 Linux


Disk /dev/loop8: 129,4 MiB, 135671808 bytes, 264984 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop9: 65,22 MiB, 68378624 bytes, 133552 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop10: 219 MiB, 229638144 bytes, 448512 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop11: 43,6 MiB, 45703168 bytes, 89264 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop12: 219 MiB, 229638144 bytes, 448512 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop13: 295,73 MiB, 310079488 bytes, 605624 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop14: 64,87 MiB, 68001792 bytes, 132816 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop15: 54,24 MiB, 56872960 bytes, 111080 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Comment: You have installed the GRUB bootloader on the SSD, and it has taken over the boot, so now you cannot boot without this disk. Verify my above statement, then follow [this link](https://aaronlauterer.com/blog/2021/move-grub-and-boot-to-other-disk/) to move GRUB to your main disk.

Comment: Your comment seems interesting, I am not sure where I should move GRUB, any idea?

Comment: Move it to the main disk. You might need to reduce some partition a little bit to give it some space.

Comment: I am new to linux and am not sure which one is the main disk, or how to reduce a partition to give it some space, could you elaborate please?

Comment: This is the internal disk, not the external one.

Comment: Physically it is the internal disk, but `fdisk -l ` returns many disks so I don't know which one it is from the list in my post

Answer (score 1):

It's normal as GRUB is installed on your SSD.

Change your Boot Order in UEFI/BIOS and recheck the behaviour. But you will still need to select from the boot menu if you want to switch OS regularly.

I have installed Dual Boot but on the same Disk. Meanwhile, if you are using Windows as primary, you can change the boot order in GRUB.

Comment: When I change the boot order, Windows launches all the time, no matter if the SSD is plugged in or not

Comment: @arnino That's what I said in the 3rd sentence above. You have three ways:
i) move GRUB to Disk in your computer,
ii) Install Ubuntu on the same disk as Windows, or
ii) Install Windows and Ubuntu in SSD